# VOIP Push "aps" key for High priority Notification - alert/badge/sound

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit

For VOIP Pushes, at client we shall use Pushkit to receive VOIP notifications.

There is some confusion with the usage of "aps" key at server. Can you confirm if by default all pushes sent using SSL certificate with voip extension are high priority pushes?

If not, & we need to set priority as high, doc says can't use high priority alone with "content_available". Does that mean silent notifications shall always be low priority even for VOIP?

If above things are valid, that means for VOIP, to make pushes high priority, its mandatory to send one of alert/sound/badge along with content-available for high priority VOIP notifications?

Shall really appreciate comments/answers on the same.

Regards,
_Ayush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pushkit voip with content_available are always high priority.**

When you check mark for VOIP while creating certificates and use that p12/pem by default it works on high priority.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit

A PKPushRegistry object requests the delivery of specialized push notifications and handles the receipt of those notifications. A push registry object manages only certain types of notifications, such as high-priority notifications needed by a VoIP app. PushKit wakes up your app as needed to deliver incoming notifications and delivers the notifications directly to the push registry object that requested them.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Just to clarify further, that means 'apns-priority' is irrelevant for Voip Push right? Also, at server that means, its just the certificate which decides if its Voip Push or normal push. Apple has come up with generic APNS SSL certificate with Voip extension. This should be analogous to existing Voip Service Certificate right?